# Shopify API calls getting 401 Error unauthorize

Tags: shopify, http-status-code-401

I am using `ShopifyAPIAdapterLibrary.ShopifyAPIClient` class (from Shopify lib) to access shop data threw the Json API inside my application.

My app was running well in the last month and after publishing to Beta version i was start getting this error :

> *The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized*

It seems like Shopify was blocked my app key from accessing Shopify stores data because the API key I am using was not changed and my app was stop working right after publishing my app to the beta version...

Is someone from Shopify knows why I am getting this (401) Unauthorized error OR how to solve this out ?

Regards,
Roee

Comment: Were you using a private App token before?  Have for all your new clients who have been installing the app are you going through the correct installation process and caching the API token for their shop?

If you don't do this, you won't be able to make authenticated calls for the client and will get the resulting 401 errors.